# Complex excel formula for calculating battery consumption

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to create an excel sheet that calculates how many seconds are left in a battery based on multiple criteria's.

So I have 4 Columns with a drop down box in the first 3 to select what kind of flashlight, what kind of battery, and what kind of add on. The fourth box is the formula, and the total seconds the flashlight duration will be, based on the options picked.

- Flashlight A = 12 Seconds
- Flashlight B = 8 Seconds *10%
- Battery A = 4 Seconds added
- Battery B = 6 Seconds added
- Add-on A Reduces battery consumption of the total battery life by 10%

So in this example how would I write the formula in excel so if someone picked Flashlight A, Battery A, and Add-on A. It will know to add (12+4)*10% and present the answer

The Curve ball is Flashlight B also reduces battery consumption by 10%. So if Flashlight B, Battery A, and Add-on A are picked. Excel would add (8+4)*20%

Answer (score 0):

assuming your four columns are A B C and D and you're doing this in row 2, in cell D2 you'd enter:

```
=(IF(A2 = "Flashlight A", 12, 8) + IF(B2 = "Battery A", 4, 6)) * IF(A2 = "Flashlight A", 1, 0.9) * IF(C2 = "Add-on A", 0.9, 1)
```

Comment: I tried something like this but I would need it to be more of checking if (A2="flashlight A", 12, 0) or if (A2= "Flashlight B", 8, 0)) + if (b2="Battery A", 4, 0) or (b2="Battery B", 6, 0)) * If (C3="Add-on A" 1.1, 1). I know this isn't correct syntax. But basically I am having trouble with excel first checking which variation is in the cell and assigning the correct value for that variation.

Comment: Look at the syntax for `IF()` - it's `=IF([Logical test], [value if true], [value if false])`. That means that where you have two options to pick from, just test if it's one of them and put the other option's value in [value if false]